# Systematic information that X provides for Y and irreducible error

Tags: machine-learning

I am referring to Figure 2.2 of the book "An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R".

[image: Figure 2.2]

The book states that the blue curve represents the true underlying relationship between income and years of education. But if the blue curve represents the true underlying relationship than the function should go through all the points, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be interpreted assuming the data generating process is
$$
Y=f(X)+\varepsilon
$$
where $f(\cdot)$ is a deterministic function while $\varepsilon$ is a stochastic error term independent of $X$. Then $f(\cdot)$ represents the so-called "true underlying relationship" and the blue line corresponds to $\hat{Y}=f(X)$. Meanwhile, the actual data points are determined by the entire data generating process including both the deterministic and the stochastic parts, $Y=f(X)+\varepsilon$. Hence, the data points differ from the blue line by $\varepsilon$.